# How to use video annotation using PDFTron for mobile iOS/Android?

Tags: android, ios, pdftron

I’m using PDFTron framework to show thumbnail and pdf on my mobile iOS/Anroid App. Currently I want to use video(annotation) to show video using PDFTron. As I’m not getting any support to implemnt video for iOS/Android mobile app.

Please suggest me if any support available to implement video using PDfTron just like images.

Implement video using PDfTron just like images.

Answer (score 1):

Viewing video annotations (RichMedia) is supported by default in the viewer on Android and iOS, however creation is not supported.

Could you tell us what kind of support you're looking for?

Please feel free to reach out to support at https://apryse.com/contact-us .